# How to display a confirmation message while switching tabs (tabPanel) within a R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to implement something similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906490/confirmation-on-switching-between-tabs) **within the app** and **not at the browser level** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048802/r-shiny-ask-confirmation-before-closing-app-tab).

After capturing the value of the new tab (tabPanel value) selected, could not display the confirmation message before switching to the newly selected tab to display its content.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyalert(),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabselected",
    tabPanel("Tab1"),
    tabPanel("Tab2",plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$tabselected, {
    if(input$tabselected == "Tab2") 
      { 
       shinyalert(title = "Save your work before changing tab", type = "warning", showConfirmButton = TRUE)
       output$plot <- renderPlot({ ggplot(mtcars)+geom_abline() })
      }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply redirect to `Tab1` via `updateTabsetPanel` as long as your desired condition is met.

Here is an example requiring the user to type something in the `textInput` before it's allowed to switch the tab.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyalert(),
                tabsetPanel(
                  id = "tabselected",
                  tabPanel("Tab1", p(), textInput("requiredText", "Required Text")),
                  tabPanel("Tab2", p(), plotOutput("plot"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tabselected, {
    if (input$tabselected == "Tab2" && !isTruthy(input$requiredText)) {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "tabselected", selected = "Tab1")
      shinyalert(title = "Save your work before changing tab",
                 type = "warning",
                 showConfirmButton = TRUE)
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars) + geom_abline() + ggtitle(req(input$requiredText))
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]

By the way an alternative approach wpuld be using `showTab` and `hideTab` to display the tabs only if all conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Great suggestions. However, I am looking for a solution to caution the user when switching between tabs accidentally when they are in middle of something in a tab section.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the desired outcome then?

Comment: As specified in the question, when the user accidentally (or purposefully) clicks another tab within the app, they should be warned with a message to save the work similar to as it happens here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048802/r-shiny-ask-confirmation-before-closing-app-tab].

Comment: So you don't want that shinyalert but a browser message instead?

Comment: I am able to create the browser warning message when a user clicks on the back button in the browser. This is switching of tabs within the app to view various tab contents. Not the change at the browser level.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but good luck.

Comment: But this 'tab-toggel' is not part of your example code above. You might consider updating your question - we can't guess your intentions.